# NextJS + Styled components + process.browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, seo

I don't know what the issue exactly is but my SEO in NextJS is not working due to `process.browser` but it used to make my site responsive.However, when I remove it SEO works fine and facebook debugger is able to extract whereas with process.browser it is not able to extract

I don't know but when I remove the `process.browser`, Styles are not loaded for mobile view, (already completed the setup of Styled components with the help of [this](https://dev.to/aprietof/nextjs--styled-components-the-really-simple-guide----101c))

Meta tags are shown in dev tools but they are not available in  `build` folder. Moreover when I remove `process.browser` it generate Meta tags and it is also available in html pages inside `build` folder and also works fine with facebook debugger

To start dev server: yarn dev or npm run dev
To build: use yarn build or npm build

Sandbox: [[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-hertz-wtozn?file=/pages/_app.js)]

Thanks in advance :)

```
_app.js

import "../styles/global.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return process.browser && <Component />;
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function Home() {
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>my site</title>
        <meta name="title" content="my site" />
        <meta name="description" content="my portfolio" />
          <meta property="og:title" content="my site" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="my portfolio" />
      </Head>
      
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

```
_document.js

import Document from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: You have to remove `process.browser`, it's forcing the components to render on the client-side only. Check the official example on how to setup styled-components with Next.js: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/main/examples/with-styled-components. See how `pages/_document`, `pages/_app` and `.babelrc` are setup there.

Comment: Already did that but it is not working somehow 